# How to get the median value in a leading moving window with same label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a 'label' column and a 'value' column. My question is how can I get the median/max/min value in a leading moving window with the same label?

e.g.

```
df = Dataframe([[1,1],[1,2],[0,3],[1,4],[0,5],[1,6],[1,7]],columns=['label','value'])

label   |   value
1       |   1
1       |   2
0       |   3
1       |   4
0       |   5
1       |   6
1       |   7
```

for **EACH** row n, I want to get median from row n-5 to row n-2 with the same label.

for example, for the last row `[1,7]`, I firstly pick up rows `[[1,2],[0,3],[1,4],[0,5]]`, then remain `[[1,2],[1,4]]` since they all have label `'1'` and finally calculate `median(2,4)/max(2,4)/min(2,4)`.

Can anyone give me some suggestions or examples for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using iloc[] and groupby(), I try this

```
df.iloc[1:5,:].groupby('label')['value'].median().loc[1]
```

Comment: Well i want to get median for each row, more like rolling().median(). But your answer specifies the row number from 1 to 5.